# what is the simplest and best way to getting data from a website

Tags: android

Actually my purpose is getting JSON data and parsing that. But I already can't enter a website and print html. What is the simplest way to getting data from a website or web service.

I tried thenewboston's tutorial but that's old and not working for new versions.

Comment: Do you own the website? Or is this a site you have no access to modify?

Comment: @JustinWood My site for now.